# How to import excel to MS Access table design?

Tags: ms-access, excel

NOTE: This is **NOT** asking how to export MS Access table design to excel. This is the opposite direction.

Given a excel sheet, it has field info (name, start position, and width). I want to export this excel sheet into MS Access table design.

The excel file:

```
Field 1 len = 3 start = 1
Field 2 len = 2 start = 4
......
```

The MS Access design table

```
Field name Field length 
Field 1    3 (to be appeared)
.......
```

Comment: Open Ms access and go to `External Data` tab then click on `Excel` icon from `Import` Group then it will open a wizard which will provide you design option as your requirements.

Comment: @JSapkota I tried, but it only import the excel file as regular data source. I did not see any design option.

Comment: Are you talking about the table definition? Or including data? Can you edit your question and paste a sample?

Comment: No data involved.

Comment: @Peter this sample OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a table using DDL (data definition language) you can use a [create table statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200.aspx)

You don't need the start or end position. But you do need a data type and field length.

With a bit of clever work in excel, you can probably generate a create statement.

Unless you are repeating this for lots of tables it might be easier just to create the table directly in Access.

Another option is to mock up a sample table in excel with your field names and a sample row of data and import it into access. That way access will select suitable data types.